# How to find road distance between two points in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am working where I need to make python scripts to find distance between set of points using any predefined library function.

While searching for same I came across Road Graph plugin of C++.

Is there any similar library for Python in PyQGIS where I can find shortest distance among two points when road line layer is given.